# Is it possible to access the email of a Lead's owner directly?

Tags: trigger, email, leads

For instance, I am writing some code to send an email using a after insert trigger. I am wanting to get the email address of the lead owner I am currently iterating over, but am running into an error.

```
public static void sendAdrEmailNotification(List<Lead> leadList) {

     ...

     for (Lead lead : leadList) {
          ...
          singleMail.setToAddresses(lead.Owner.Email); //Email cannot be resolved
          ...
     }
}
```

How can I get the email address of the lead owner in the Apex code? I know I can use a SOQL query but I obviously do not want to do this in a for loop so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Lead owner can be a USer or a Queue, so you have to work accordingly.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal What's strange is `SELECT Id, Owner.Email FROM Lead` works in a SOQL query so I'm not sure why it doesn't work in Apex. I know formulas use `Lead.Owner:User.Email` syntax, I just don't know what the syntax is in Apex

Comment: You can create a formula field on lead, and then use that in APex code. Formula field values can be accessed in after trigger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need soql to do that, you can directly use **setTargetObjectId**

> **setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId)**
>
> optional . The ID of the contact, lead, or user to which the
>   email will be sent. The ID you specify sets the context and ensures
>   that merge fields in the template contain the correct data.Required if using a template,

so your code will be

```
for (Lead lead : leadList) {
          ...
           if(lead.OwnerId.getSobjectType() ==  User.SObjectType)
          singleMail.setTargetObjectId(lead.OwnerId); 
          ...
     }
```

The advantage of using setTargetObjectId is, you can send unlimited emails to the user. If manually specify email id then you are restricted to only 5000 emails a day limit.

src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm

Comment: Thanks @Pranay this resolved it. Also I think you meant to say my code should be `singleMail.setTargetObjectId(lead.OwnerId);` in your code block

Comment: @Josh yeah I meant that, :P I forgot to change , My bad

Comment: @Prany, I may have to open a new question, but I'm attempting to use an email template here, using `setWhatId` which should fill out the template, but you cannot use both `setWhatId` and `setTargetObjectId` together or you get an error. Where can I go from here?

Comment: You dont have to use setWhatID if you use setTargetObjectId check the link I mentioned for setTargetId

Comment: Ah, but then it'll try to use the lead owner to fill in the fields instead of the lead object, right? The fields in my template are all based off of the lead object

Comment: Why not use `renderEmailTemplate` method to get merged email data for lead? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm

Comment: Thanks, that worked and now everything is up and running!